# onDraw() doesn't getting called after invalidate

Tags: android, ondraw, invalidation

I have the custom view, (it extends View class), it's updated from the Adapter's getView():

```
 public void setProgress(float progressDegrees) {
        this.progressDegrees = progressDegrees;
        invalidate();
 }
```

I've tried to add setWillNotDraw(false) call to the constructor, view's visibility is View.VISIBLE, but onDraw() does not getting called. Why?

Comment: because, that's how works UI thread ... invalidate means: "call onDraw on next message peek from UI thread" so if you are callin setProgress in loop on UI thread onDraw will not called

Comment: it is something like: `while(uiExists) { var msg = peekMessage(); switch(msg){ case onDraw: callOnDraw(); break; case someOther: callMyLoopWithSetProgress = { loop{ invalidate = {postMessage(onDraw)} } } } }` <= as you can see it will be in the same run of while UI loop